# Handling query in React and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

Somewhere in my React application I used REST API to send request to the server. In my URL I want to use query (in the `postIconsTransition method`), but when I send a request to the server, server tells me could not found this URL (I build this error in my server). If I use this URL without any query the request in the `postIconsTransition method` works fine. `postId` and `authContext.userId` work fine, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

In my component where I send request:

```
  const likeHandler = async () => {
    setLike(prevState => !prevState);

    if (!like) {
      try {
        await postIconsTransition(props.postId, "inc");
      } catch (error) {}
    } else {
      try {
        await postIconsTransition(props.postId, "dec");
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  };
```

In `useHttp.js` component:

```
  const postIconsTransition = async (postId, addtionAddress) => {
    return await transitionData(
      `http://localhost:5000/post/${postId}/${authContext.userId}?t=${addtionAddress}`,
      "POST",
      null,
      { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` }
    );
  };
```

transitionData method:

```
  const transitionData = useCallback(
    async (url, method = "GET", body = null, headers = {}) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const abortController = new AbortController();
      activeHttpRequest.current.push(abortController);

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method,
          body,
          headers,
          signal: abortController.signal
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();

        activeHttpRequest.current = activeHttpRequest.current.filter(
          reqCtrl => reqCtrl !== abortController
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(responseData.message);
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
        return responseData;
      } catch (error) {
        modalContext.err(error);
        setIsLoading(false);
        throw error;
      }
    },
    [modalContext.err]
  );
```

In Express:

```
router.post(
  "/:postId/:userId?t=inc",
  tokenChecker,
  postController.updateLikesComments
);

router.post(
  "/:postId/:userId?t=dec",
  tokenChecker,
  postController.updateLikesComments
);
```

All of them work fine but when I use query in my URL, it's not working any more.

Comment: Both endpoints are the same path. You should check the query param inside the route handler and act based on it's value.

Comment: Just have one route `/:postId/:userId`, then check the query parameters inside the handler.

Comment: I don't think you can put query parameters in your express routes. Either use `"/:postId/:userId/inc"` instead, or `"/:postId/:userId"` and check `req.params.t` inside.

Comment: I see you are a new user. Please check stackoverflow user guides and please check this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11619647/emiel-zuurbier Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify query parameters in express routes like that. Just send them. Express can read it.

```
router.post(
  "/:postId/:userId",
  tokenChecker,
  postController.updateLikesComments
);

// Notice that you don't need the other one.
```

and in your controller check the parameter

```
// controller's code

const t = req.query.t;

if (t === 'inc') {
 // do what you want here
}

if (t === 'dec') {
 // do what you want here
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10530420/mansur Thanks dude.